# How to load class/library in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a library called **lib**, which contains a class called **nusoap.php**. I have put lib inside the folder **application/libraries/**.

When I try to load it, I'm getting the following error:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested class: nusoap
```

This the code I use to load it

```
class Dealership extends Controller
{
    function Dealership()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->library('nusoap.php');         
    }

}
```

Am I missing anything?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You dont need the `.php` extension in the `$this->load->library()` call
2. The code igniter function that loads libraries does not (unfortunately) search the libraries directory recursively, so if you want to load libs in subfolders you need to do this:

   `$this->load->library('lib/nusoap')`

From the [docs (Loader class)](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html):

> > Library files can be stored in subdirectories within the main "libraries" folder, or within your personal application/libraries
> >     folder. To load a file located in a subdirectory, simply include the
> >     path, relative to the "libraries" folder. For example, if you have
> >     file located at:
>
> libraries/flavors/chocolate.php You will load it using:
>
> `$this->load->library('flavors/chocolate');`
>
> You may nest the file in as
>   many subdirectories as you want.

Comment: I added .php then removed, but no better result.

Comment: @Richard77 can you post the class code for nusoap.php? Have you created a property for the code Igniter instance reference?

Comment: nusoap.php is a big class to post it here. Here's the download link http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/files/latest/download. How do I create created a property for the code Igniter instance reference? I'm sorry, this is the first time I do CodeIgniter and PHP.

Comment: Very strange. When I add "lib/nusoap" then a I get a different error saying: **no-existent class.**

Comment: @Richard77 its because the class name in nusoap.php is nusoap_base, i would try changing the class name to `Class nusoap` - hopefully it wont cause problems with the existing library

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41830/discussion-between-leemo-and-richard77)

Answer (score 4):

Non-existent class: xxx

Avoid use of namespaces