# Load external library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, libraries, getid3

How can I access the getid3 class and use it in my controller?

```
project
 /application
 /controller
 /libraries
    /getID3
       /getid3
          getid3.php
 /model
 /views
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182724/how-to-load-class-library-in-codeigniter)

Comment: getid3.php's code is written in codeigniter syntaxes? or it's totally diffrent ?

Comment: @Bhavin it's a different code. An external library.

Comment: @Regolith 'Unable to load the requested class: Getid3'

Comment: @OwenBula. Ok see my answer.

Comment: is the first letter of your class capital like this: `class Getid3 {}`?

Comment: Hi you can try on this link reference [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511636/custom-classes-in-codeigniter#9526005) Hope this works.

Answer (score 2):

Use CodeIgniter's built in constant, `APPPATH`. (Because code is not written in codeigniter's syntaxes)

```
`require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/getID3/getid3/getid3.php');`
```

If this library is codeigniter's built in library then you should use.

```
$this->load->library('libary name');
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Your File Structure `Codeigniter` has the solution for it:

```
project
/application
/controller
/libraries
    /getID3
        /getid3
            getid3.php
/model
/views
```

Now To call the `Getid3.php`  the library you need to add this below code in the controller.

```
$this->load->library ( 'getID3/getid3/getid3', '', 'getid3(you can add any name you want' );
```

Now to Use this:

```
$this->getid3->your_function($data);
```

Please Note that `Getid3.php` must start with the capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

From [CI Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html?highlight=load%20library#CI_Loader::library)

you can load library by doing

```
$this->load->library('getID3/getid3/Getid3');
```

As explained in documentation if you have file located in a subdirectory like

`libraries/flavors/Chocolate.php`
You will load it using:

`$this->load->library('flavors/chocolate');`

Comment: your file name should be like this `Getid3.php`. see [File Naming](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

Answer (score 0):

You COULD just do a require_once on the main GetID3.php file

`require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/getID3/getid3/getid3.php');`

but there are better, more cleaner ways, to manage this third party dependency.

Instead of directly requiring the GetID3.php file, I recommend creating a wrapper class for the library. Creating a wrapper class affords you the ability to extend/overwrite the getid3 library and provides a cleaner implementation by allowing you to do things the "codeigniter way".

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class GetID3 {  

    function __construct ( $options = array() )
    {
        require_once( APPPATH . 'third_party/getID3/getid3/getid3.php' );
    }

    public function __get( $var ) { return get_instance()->$var; }
}
```

Doing it this way provides a cleaner interface to work with and allows for a more scalable approach to managing the third party dependency. Also, not the directory structure. Here, we are saving third party dependencies to the third_party directory while saving the wrapper class to libraries/GetID3.php.

Once you've implemented it this way, you can load the library as you normally would:

```
$this->load->library('GetID3');
```